# Swift - Tell TableViewController what data to populate with

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a table view populated with cells containing the user's friends. A cell, when selected, should pull up that friend's profile. However, while the profile view does show up, I don't know how to tell its view controller to load that friend's profile data. How do you have two view controllers communicate with each other in response to user action? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have two view controllers:
destinationVC and sourceVC

Create optional variables in destinationVC to store values which you want to share between the VC's.

In the sourceVC

- override prepareForSegue method
- obtain the destinationVC using `segue.destinationViewController` and store the returned value in a variable, say destVC
- initialise the optional variables of destVC with values from selected cell
- you can obtain the selected cell by using `tableview.cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow())`
- get data from selected cell and assign it to destVC's variables

Then in the destVC

- In the viewDidLoad method
- Check if the optional variables are not nil
- Use the values of variables to load/update the destVC.

Edit: Updated answer according to Mike Taverne's comment.

Comment: You don't initialize a destinaton view controller in prepareForSegue. You access it via segue.destinationViewController.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "user" property of that "destination" view controller in your current view controller:

Set a selectedUser property in your current view controller:

```
class CurrentTableViewController: TableViewController {

    var selectedUser: AnyObject?

    ...
}
```

Then when that friend's cell is selected, set the "selectedUser" property in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath":

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.selectedUser = // get the user property depending on how you're defining your table cells in the first place
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("pushToUser", sender: self)
}
```

Next in your prepareForSegue method, define the destination view controller and set its "user" property from the "self.selectedUser" property:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "pushToUser") {
        var userProfileTableViewController: UserProfileTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UserProfileTableViewController
        userProfileTableViewController.user = self.selectedUser
    }
}
```

Last, in the destination view controller (which in this case is UserProfileTableViewController) you can call your database queries, etc. using "self.user".

Comment: objectForIndexPath is for NSFetchedResultsControllers. OP did not say he is using this type of controller. Also worth pointing out that selectedUser and user are custom properties that must be defined for this code to work. Your opening line implies the user property exists already.